# Slant asymptote

Tags: calculus

I have this function: $f(x)=\frac{x\ln x}{1+\ln x}$ I found for the derivative $f'(x)=1-\frac{\ln x}{(1+\ln x)^2}$It is easy to verify that for $x$ to infinity, that derivative $f'(x)$ goes to $1$ And so I am to believe that this graph has a slant asymptote of the form $y=x+b$ But I fail to find this $b$ value. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{\log x}{1+\log x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)-x\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}-\frac x{1+\log x}=-\infty$$

Thus, there is no slanted asymptote.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out by using the definition of the asymptote by taking limit x to inf trying to establish $f(x)-(mx+b)=0$ and I failed. But here is the thing: The derivative approaches $1$, meaning a finite value. I am surprised that there is no slant asymptote.

Comment: Well, there you go: you've found, by means of a nice example, why the derivative's limit is *cannot* be defined as the presumed asymptote's slope...:)

Comment: This is revealing to say the least. At school we are so much used to find the slant asymptote of a rational function where the degree of the num is one higher than of the denom. That derivative also goes to a fixed value. I stumbled on my posted example actually by surprise and..learned something today. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: On a side note, I just realized that the derivative of $y=lnx$ also goes to zero for x to infinity, but this function has no horizontal asymptote either. Kind a makes sense now...